# How to overload the arrow dereference operator->() not for solid objects but for pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I know how to overload operator-> for solid (stack) objects (like smart pointers)

```
#include <iostream>
struct A { void foo() {} };
struct B {
    A* pa;
    A* operator->() {
        return pa;
    }
};
int main() {
    B b;
    b->foo();  // b is SOLID object on stack: b.pa = ...
}
```

But I want this:

```
B * pb = new B();
pb->foo(); // to call my overload
```

I need this for the Database Manager Singleton design:

```
class DatabaseManager
{
private:
    static DatabaseManager * sharedInstance_;
    sqdb::Db *db = nullptr;

public:
    static DatabaseManager * instance();
    sqdb::Db * operator->() {
        return db;
    }
}
```

I want basically this behavior

```
auto m = DatabaseManager::instance();
m->Query(...); // db->Query
```

Comment: It would be `(*pb)->foo();`. You cannot overload `operator ->` for pointer

Comment: You can't. There's no overloading of built-in operators.

Comment: You can't do this. Why do you want to?

Comment: @Jarod42 but it is ugly.... ((

Comment: @Kevin I have a singleton DatabaseManager::instance() that returns a pointer and I want to use operator->() call to forward transparently every method call to underlying Database * pointer

Comment: @barney Why not have `instance()` return the correct type?

Comment: Why not returning a reference ?

Comment: Why not have a conversion operator?

Comment: @Jarod42 Its not possible with singleton - if I return a reference to object in heap - it calls destructor when the reference leaves the some local scope.

Comment: @Jarod42 
struct DatabaseManager
{
    static DatabaseManager * sharedInstance_;
    static DatabaseManager & instance() {
        if (!sharedInstance_) {
         sharedInstance_ = new DatabaseManager();
     }
        return *sharedInstance_;
    }
};  then somewhere:

{ auto m = DatabaseManager::instance(); } <-- would deallocate the singleton

Comment: @barney the C++ way of making a singleton (in C++11 at least) is something like this: `Singleton& instance() { static Singleton s; return s; }` No pointers, no heap.

Comment: You misuse the singleton: copy/assignment methods should be deleted.

Comment: @barney You should read up on pointers/references. References don't cause destructors to be called when they leave scope. Also destructors are never automatically called for new'ed objects, which is why they're generally frowned upon in modern C++ (since you need to remember to manually call `delete`).

Comment: @Kevin I updated the description

Comment: @Jarod42 I see...

Comment: @barney Why not have `DatabaseManager::instance()` return a `sqdb::Db*`? What do you expect to do with a `DatabaseManager*` besides accessing the underlying db with ->? If you want to access something in `DatabaseManager` through the pointer you'd need to do `(*instance).something` which is really awkward.

Comment: @Kevin  If I make this static local object for the singleton - will there be any issues with ORDER of initialization between the .cpp modules? I mean when something is using this reference from other module that is initialized earlier but the object of DM isn't constructed yet?

Comment: @barney C++ guarantees that local static variables aren't initialized until the first time the function is called. C++11 guarantees that this is a thread-safe operation.

Comment: @Kevin I have some methods that belong to the Manager than the Database. But yes this is awkward design. Ideally I just want to forward only the Query method call to the Database object (Maybe its easier just to make forwarding Query() method in the DM itself... )

Comment: @Jarod42 about the copy of singleton ref. So when I use auto dm = DM::instance() it returns a reference and MAKES A solid object COPY, right? But how can I deduce dm to be a reference itself? I.e without explicit auto &

Comment: I copy is deleted, `auto dm = DM::instance();` won't compile and you have indeed to use `auto&` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, I see... This is very insightful... Each time when I write auto a=getRefToA() I really need to think about the copy construction )) I wrongly assumed that a would deduce to the reference type itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot replace `->` on a pointer.

You can create a smart pointer<sup>1</sup> that overloads `->`, but built-in operators may not be overloaded.

```
auto m = DatabaseManager::instance();
m->Query(...); // db->Query
```

This is no problem, but tye type of `m` isn't a pointer.  It would be some `struct` or `class` with an overloaded `operator->`.

Such a class could just be a thin wrapper around a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, and `->` could return `&(ptr.get()->db)` for example.

The dumbest way to do this is

```
class DatabaseManager {
  struct DatabaseManagerPtr {
    DatabaseManager* ptr;
    sqdb::Db * operator->() {
      return ptr?ptr->db:nullptr;
    }
  };
  friend struct DatabaseManagerPtr;
private:
  static DatabaseManager * sharedInstance_;
  sqdb::Db *db = nullptr;

public:
  static DatabaseManagerPtr instance() {
    return {sharedInstance_};
  }
};
```

which makes your "I want this to work" code work exactly as is, but there are many more clever ways to do this (that may involve slight tweaks to your "I want this to work" code)

---

<sup>1</sup> In C++, a smart pointer is any type that acts sort of like a pointer, but is somehow "smarter" than a raw pointer in a reasonably justified way.  Maybe it is just wearing a fancier suit; C++ isn't very elitist about calling things "smart" pointers.

Comment: Thanks this is very illuminating. But why we cannot overload operators for typed pointers? Any typed pointer is not just void* it has information of its type so when we apply -> to the pointer-to-some-struct isn't it enough for the compiler to use this "Type*" as the information to overload the desired operator somehow?

Comment: @barney Because the standard says you cannot.  The standard says you cannot because the committee and language designers decided it shouldn't. I believe the committee decided you cannot overload built-in operators because they wanted the semantics of built-in operators to be fixed and able to be understood by a programmer. The closest you can get to overloading built-in operators in C++ is adding an overload for an `enum`, which in the absence of such an overload implicitly converts to an integral type and the built-in operator then works. There is no technical barrier; it is barred by design.

Comment: Sure, that's exactly what I tried to understand: the reason behind their decision. The use semantics they are enforcing by the rules. Btw, the main issue here was in psychology - I intuitively (wrongly) assumed that typed pointers are subjects to operator overloading. And vice versa - when the "dereference field access" operator in fact is applied for the solid objects and isn't dereferencing the incoming object (but the dereference is applied at the end - to the returned pointer-to-object by this operator). Mind bending!) But still good for smart_pointers with distinct "." and -> calls

Answer (score 1):

The rule is:

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

and

> When operator-> returns, the operator -> is applied to the value
>   returned, with the original second operand.

Too understand more easily: only chained calls of `.operator->()` can be reduced to a single `->` and then also the following dereference of a pointer will be also "reduced".

So in this case Just change the `instance` function to return `DatabaseManager&`

Comment: So, the final ->m would anyway dereference the whatever returned from the nested call - before applying m? and it should be a pointer, right?

Comment: Only under the assumption that it was precceded by ```.operator->()``` up the whole chain before it. Which is not possible for a pointer at the beggining.